# Activity Slide from left to right

Tags: android

I have two Activities named `MainActivity` and `SecondActivity`. I need to move the `MainActivity` from left to right and then launch `SecondActivity`. This is my code:

```
Intent slideactivity = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Second.class);
startActivity(slideactivity);
overridePendingTransition(android.R.anim.slide_in_left, android.R.anim.slide_out_right);
```

In an emulator I can see the `MainActivity` moving from left to right. But on an Android device, it slides very fast.
Please, how can I keep duration from Android Emulator?

Thank you.

Comment: create your own animation files and increase duration of animation in it.

Comment: I have tried that approach also, under anim folder am having files like this:slide_in_left & slide_out_right with duration 500. I ave incresed the duration also, but not helpfull.

Comment: Increase your duration...........

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried setting the animation in your second class before you set the content View?

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_left, R.anim.slide_out_right);

        setContentView(R.layout.second_activity_layout);

        //your other code
}
```

Other than that, are you sure you've increased the duration of the translate aspect of the animation xml and not the alpha?

**EDIT**

As for the sliding menu you can could look in to using the android navigation drawer

[Android navigation Drawer](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation-drawer.html)

Or a library such as

[Sliding Menu](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu)

Comment: wow!! U pointed me in right direction. This works fine now.. I have a  question, I want to bring second_activity_layout 80% of the screen & rest 20% of the screen will be MainActivity. when i move the secondactivity from left to right, at the same time MainActivity doesnot move from left to right. Can u suggest me how to achieve this ?

Comment: Are you saying you want the second activity to be layered over the first activity for the length of the the activities lifecycle?
If so you'll have to look in to using Fragments, as this cannot be achieved just using activities. Are you trying to achieve a sliding menu type effect?

Also, if you feel your primary question has been solved can you please accept the answer.

Comment: yeah, Exactly sliding menus effect. Thanks for the solution.

Comment: Updated answer with links. I Hope you find what you need.

Answer (score 0):

write your own custom animation slideinleft.xml . Here you can change the duration.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator">
    <translate android:fromXDelta="-100%p" android:toXDelta="0"
        android:duration="2000" />
</set>
```

Comment: Yeah, this also works fine for me.. I have a question, I want to bring second_activity_layout 80% of the screen & rest 20% of the screen will be MainActivity. when i move the secondactivity from left to right, at the same time MainActivity doesnot move from left to right. Can u suggest me how to achieve this ?